# How can I launch a function at a specific time in C++?

Tags: c++, time

Is is possible to call a function at a specific time in C++? For example, I would like to launch function doIt() when number_of_elapsed_milliseconds_since_application_start = x.

A cross-platform solution would be ideal.

Comment: launch new thread.  `sleep(number_of_elapsed_milliseconds_since_application_start); doit();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pure C++ probably not, you will need some OS specific code. But you can use a platform-independent OS-wrapper, like Qt (although this could be a bit of an overkill for your quite simple problem).

**EDIT:** The simplest thing you could do, is actively blocking the program in a loop, that constantly polls the current time, until the deadline is reached, but that is probably not a very useful solution. So without threads or some event-driven timer (as every OS should have) you won't get very far.

Comment: I think every major OS has the `sleep` function, which is really all you need for nonstandard code.

Comment: @MooingDuck Well, of course with the advent of C++11 my answer doesn't make that much sense.

Answer (score 3):

Make a thread, put it to sleep until that time, and after the sleep, have it run that function.

Comment: +1, though I would note that we are not using real time OS, so the thread won't wake up at exactly the time scheduled, it'll be a bit off, how much depending on the current machine load.

Answer (score 1):

This is what's considered a 'CallBack' function or a 'listener'. More information on implementing it can be found here: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html

Hope that helps.